# MS-Access - Does not include * as part of an aggregate function...but it is

Tags: ms-access, aggregate-functions

I get "Your query does not include the specified expression "SalesTransactions.Qty" as part of an aggregate function." with the following code:

```
SELECT SalesTransactions.[Stock#], Sum(SalesTransactions.Qty) AS SumOfQty,
Sum(SalesTransactions.Retail) AS SumOfRetail,
Max(SalesTransactions.TransDate) AS MaxOfTransDate,
Max(InvReport.Description) AS MaxOfDescription, Max(InvReport.QOH) AS MaxOfQOH, 
Max(InvReport.[Vnd1#]) AS [MaxOfVnd1#], Max(InvReport.LastCost) AS MaxOfLastCost
FROM InvReport INNER JOIN SalesTransactions ON InvReport.[Stock#] = SalesTransactions.[Stock#]
GROUP BY SalesTransactions.[Stock#]
ORDER BY SalesTransactions.Qty DESC;
```

but it seems to be part of an aggregate function - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
order by SalesTransactions.Qty desc;
```

You can't use `SalesTransactions.Qty` directly in the order by after aggregation as it is not in the `group by` clause:

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
select SalesTransactions.[Stock#],
    Sum(SalesTransactions.Qty) as SumOfQty,
    Sum(SalesTransactions.Retail) as SumOfRetail,
    Max(SalesTransactions.TransDate) as MaxOfTransDate,
    Max(InvReport.Description) as MaxOfDescription,
    Max(InvReport.QOH) as MaxOfQOH,
    Max(InvReport.[Vnd1#]) as [MaxOfVnd1#],
    Max(InvReport.LastCost) as MaxOfLastCost
from InvReport
inner join SalesTransactions on InvReport.[Stock#] = SalesTransactions.[Stock#]
group by SalesTransactions.[Stock#]
order by SumOfQty desc;
```